# JQGrid filterToolbar row hidden when grid loads

Tags: jqgrid

Found the documentation here

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching

**I want JQgrid filterToolbar blank top row in the grid hidden till the user use Toggle button to show. How do I do that?**

```
myGrid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false },{}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false });
    myGrid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, defaultSearch: 'cn' });
    myGrid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager',{ caption: "Filter", title: "Toggle Searching Toolbar",buttonicon: 'ui-icon-pin-s',onClickButton: function () { myGrid[0].toggleToolbar(); }});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you need just add one more line at the end of your code:

```
myGrid[0].toggleToolbar();
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbar1.htm).

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved through below code snippet.

```
jQuery("ui-search-toolbar").hide();
```